# Get subdomain in Twig

Tags: twig

So currently I use `app.request.getHttpHost()` to get the whole domain and then implement specific output depending on the subdomain:

```
{% set domain = app.request.getHttpHost() %}
{% if (domain == 'de.domain.com') %}
    {{ do_something }}
{% endif %}
```

But I'd prefer getting only the current subdomain (in this case 'de'), so I could do something like this:

```
{% if (subdomain == 'de') %}
    {{ do_something }}
{% endif %}
```

Is there a way to implement this check?

Comment: I was able to _kind of_ do it by using app.request.getHttpHost()[:2], so that the output of this function is only the first two symbols of the host. But since subdomains may be of different length, it's not really a perfect solution.

Comment: what about `{% set subdomain = "de.domain.com"|split('.')|first %}` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A more elegant solution could be:

```
{{ "de.domain.com"|split('.')|first }}
{# outputs "de" #}
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you. I used `{% set subdomain = app.request.getHttpHost()|split('.')|first %}`. This works.